# 32-bit future as this is based on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, 32-bit

With Ubuntu stating they will be removing 32-bit package support, I would assume Elementary OS will follow the same path eventually since the repositories are based on that.

I was considering promoting Elementary OS for some clients who currently use Windows, but would like to use something else.

My experience with Elementary indicates this would be a great way to get them off Windows. However, due to the lack of future support for 32-bit libraries and the likely need for Wine of some sort, I can no longer recommend any Ubuntu based distribution.

Is there any plan on the Elementary OS side to support 32-bit packages after Ubuntu 19 ceases support?

I've heard that Ubuntu plans to continue support for Wine in a snap, based on Ubuntu 18. This is a non-starter from my perspective.